# SAP Vora Thrift Server Error: Instantiating dialect 'sapsql' failed

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hana, vora

I have deployed a `cloudera CDH 5.13.1` Cluster with `SAP Vora 1.4 Patch 4`.

When I started the `Vora thrift` server everything looks fine, but as soon as I start `SAP Vora tools` and login following error shows up:

```
17/12/20 11:26:52 ERROR thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error executing query, currentState RUNNING, 
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$DialectException: Instantiating dialect 'sapsql' failed.
Reverting to default dialect 'sapsql'
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.getSQLDialect(SQLContext.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.getSQLDialect(HiveContext.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.SapHiveContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SapHiveContext.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.SapHiveContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SapHiveContext.scala:54)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:135)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:202)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2.apply(Parsers.scala:890)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$$anon$1.apply(PackratParsers.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.SapHiveContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SapHiveContext.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.SapHiveContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SapHiveContext.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DDLParser.parse(DDLParser.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parseSql(SQLContext.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.parseSql(HiveContext.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:829)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:211)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.extension.SapSQLDialect
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.getSQLDialect(SQLContext.scala:215)
    ... 54 more
```

In the installation guide it says I need to assign the vora user authorization for the Hive Metastore.

Since this is only a test setup authorization is disabled in Hive and the vora user can create and drop tables in the default database and has write access to Hive's warehouse location.

How can I solve it?

Comment: The client version of `Vora tools` is `1.4.21` whereas the parcel version is `1.4.0.34-vora-1.4` could this cause the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by an incompatability with CDH 5.13 and Vora 1.4 patch 4. The issue is currently being investigated by SAP.

Is it an option for you to move to a newer Vora version? Current version is Vora 2.1. Since version 2.0 Vora is deployed in a Kubernetes cluster instead of the Hadoop cluster. This could help to overcome this CDH dependency issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which earlier version can I use that doesnt have the issue?

Comment: The fix is planned to be released with patch 6.